# 'React/UIView+React.h' file not found | AIRGMSMarker.h

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

**Intro**

Hi there! I'm working on my first react-native app. After months of work, I am finally ready to deploy to Test Flight. I built the project in expo. Runs great on the expo simulator. Next step, run in Xcode. I encountered a few errors but managed to find my way. Until, I hit this error, which, I just cannot seem to get around.

**What I have done:**

1)Ejected ExpoKit

2)Run npm install

3)Run pod install in my ios directory

**The Error:**

Now, I am trying to compile in debug and release configurations but the build fails :(. [Here is the error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtlR9.jpg)

Not sure what to do. I have searched all around and can't seem to find a working solution... Any ideas??

**Versions**

- React Native - 0.54.2
- React Native CLI - 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with these steps

- update pod
- install pod
- removed node_modules and npm install

Not sure this will help anyone but it fixed my problem.